# Handling SOAP XML when Element isn't present

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap

The SOAP response i'm getting may or may not have a specific element in the response.  The element  "GetRateQuoteResponse/GetRateQuoteResult/TotalAccessorialCharge"
may be returned depending on the query I make n the web-service.
I can't see to find the correct way to test existence of the elements presence.
Right now I'm setting an error trap with a TRY block to catch and bypass the error.  I'd rather do it the correct way.

Any help will be gladly appreciated

Point of failure (before adding the try block)

Dim Tcharge As Double = Convert.ToDouble(cfnroot.SelectNodes("GetRateQuoteResponse/GetRateQuoteResult/TotalAccessorialCharge").Item(0).InnerText)

Comment: Does `Double.TryParse(cfnroot.SelectNodes("GetRateQuoteResponse/GetRateQuoteResult/TotalAccessorialCharge").Item(0).InnerText,Tcharge)` also return an error or assign a value of 0 to `Tcharge`?

Comment: I've tried it as is and it throws the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Check if the node `IsNothing` and code accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?  Testing if SelectNodes returns any nodes in the nodelist before trying to access the values.

```
Dim Tcharge As Double 

If cfnroot.SelectNodes("GetRateQuoteResponse/GetRateQuoteResult/TotalAccessorialCharge").Count > 0 Then
  Tcharge = Convert.ToDouble(cfnroot.SelectNodes("GetRateQuoteResponse/GetRateQuoteResult/TotalAccessorialCharge").Item(0).InnerText)
Else
  ' do something when node(s) aren't present?
End If
```

Comment: With or without the element present:
?cfnroot.SelectNodes("GetRateQuoteResponse/GetRateQuoteResult/TotalAccessorialCharge")  isnot nothing    

Returns True

If I dump to my immediate window after visually making sure the node is not present this is what I get. It returns TRUE to the Isnot Nothing clause . 
?cfnroot.SelectNodes("GetRateQuoteResponse/GetRateQuoteResult/TotalAccessorialCharge") 
{System.Xml.XPathNodeList}
    Count: 0
    done: True
    list: Count = 0

Comment: @dashley, based on your comments, I've updated the proposed example code to check the nodelist count, this presumes for your situation that the `SelectNodes` method will always return a nodelist, even if it's an empty one (count=0).

Comment: Mark, Works like a charm and don't I feel dumb Ha Ha. The old adage it takes another set of eyes..  seems to be true here. I had used.

  Try

   CtlFLratedata.accessorialcharge = Convert.ToDouble(cfnroot.SelectNodes("GetRateQuoteResponse/GetRateQuoteResult/TotalAccessorialCharge").Item(0).InnerText)

  Catch ex As Exception

   CtlFLratedata.accessorialcharge = 0

  End Try

I like your way better :) Thank you very much